# How to solve "Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing updateData, NOT_FOUND: No document to update:"

Tags: firebase, flutter, updates

My edit class.

```
import 'package:finalyearproject/model/NewUser.dart';
import 'package:finalyearproject/service/database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';




class UpdateSupervisor extends StatefulWidget {

  final NewUser sv;

  UpdateSupervisor({Key key, this.sv}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UpdateSupervisorState createState() => _UpdateSupervisorState();
}


class _UpdateSupervisorState extends State<UpdateSupervisor> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  TextEditingController _name;
  TextEditingController _email;
  TextEditingController _nophone;
  TextEditingController _uniqueID;


  var uuid = Uuid();

@override
void initState(){
     super.initState();
     _name = TextEditingController(text:  widget.sv.name);
     _email = TextEditingController(text:  widget.sv.email);
     _nophone = TextEditingController(text: widget.sv.nophone);
     _uniqueID= TextEditingController(text: widget.sv.uniqueID);
  }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Edit Supervisor'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
          ),
          body: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Name',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    controller: _name,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Email',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    controller: _email,

                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Number Phone',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: _nophone,

                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Unique ID ',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: _uniqueID,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      textColor: Colors.black,
                      child: Text( "Update"),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          DatabaseService().updateData(NewUser(name: _name.text, email: _email.text, nophone: _nophone.text, uniqueID: _uniqueID.text, id: uuid.v4()));
                        }
                      }
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
      );
    }
  }
```

My function update

```
 // update data supervisor
    Future updateData(NewUser newUser) async {
     
        return supervisorCollection.document(newUser.id).updateData(
            newUser.toJson()).whenComplete(() {
          print("Update success!");
        });
    }
```

This is my console firebase

[supervisor collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsLAO.png)

here is my error

Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing updateData, NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/finalyearproject-5c689/databases/(default)/documents/Supervisor/3dbac00b-29ad-4357-a480-e38a21c90042, null)

I had try using setData() for my update function but it will add new data, not updating the existing data. So someone can help me to solve this problem? is there anything that i missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uuid.v4() will generate a v4 (random) id and you are trying to update a document with this new randomly generated ID which does not exist in your collection.

to fix it:

```
var id = widget.sv.id;
```

use this id in your new user to send to update function:

```
DatabaseService().updateData(NewUser(name: _name.text, email: _email.text, nophone: _nophone.text, uniqueID: _uniqueID.text, id: id));
```

Comment: Oh i forget to explain. I using uuid.v4() because before this, when i want to add data into the firestore, my id in supervisor collection will become null value. So that is why I use uuid.v4()

Comment: i will suggest to not get a new id using uuid.v4() and use the previous id using widget.sv.id

Comment: don't change your update function.  just give the id that you get from widget.sv.id and give it to the new user that you are sending to your update function.